# Can I order Joomla error messages?

Tags: php, error-handling, joomla

I use `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('Message goes here', 'error')` to show users the request could not be processed, it works OK but Joomla orders the messages in the sequence they occur. Because my message happens before the Joomla save error is captured, the user sees this message:

```
you cannot do this operation           //my message
Save failed with the following error:  //Joomla message
```

I want to invert the order and have Joomla message as it is, followed by my message so that it makes sense:

```
Save failed with the following error:    // Joomla message
you cannot do this operation            // my message
```

Is that possible? (without language translation or overrides?)

After help from answers, I could do the inversion: 1st message is a placeholder to be searched using getMessageQueue(). Although you could delete messages in J.2.5 it is no longer possible with J.3+ (https://developer.joomla.org/joomlacode-archive/issue-33270.html). The solution is to reflect the class to unprotect the queue and replace it.

```
public static function reorderMessages()
{
    //error messages
    $err01 = JText::_('COM_COMPONENT_MESSAGE1');
    //you can adapt and add other messages here

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();  
    $new_messages = array();
    $replacement_found = null;
    //mirror protected $_messageQueue
    $appReflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($app));
    $_messageQueue = $appReflection->getProperty('_messageQueue');
    $_messageQueue->setAccessible(true);
    //get messages
    $messages = $app->getMessageQueue();

    foreach($messages as $key=>$message) 
    {  
        if($messages[$key]['message'] == 'MESSAGE_TO_REPLACE' && $messages[$key]['type'] ==  'error' ) 
        {
            $replacement_found = 1;
            continue;
        }
        $new_messages[] = $message;
    }           
    if($replacement_found)
    { 
      //save all messages
      $_messageQueue->setValue($app, $new_messages);
      //add replacement message to the end of the queue       
      $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_($err01, 'error'); 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Be very careful where to call the function, if the message queue is empty Joomla will return an error and break your code. Make sure you have enqueued the 1st message before calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getMessageQueue()` on the application object (i.e., `$myApp = JFactory::getApplication()`) to get a copy of the message queue array. You can clear the message queue by passing `true` to the getMessageQueue()` function call. It will still return a copy of the system message queue array.

You could then use regex's to find the keys in the array and reorder them. I would find the system error message in the translation file, and use the error message key from the translation `.ini` file (instead of the actual text of the error message) for the regex search so it doesn't break if the error message changes. I'd also do it in a plugin and on a late lifecycle hook (maybe the `onBeforeRender` event).

You can save the modified message queue array back to the `JApplication` class instance using the application object's `enqueueMessage()` method, which has this signature:

`enqueueMessage(string $msg, string $type = 'message') : void`

[source](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not know about getMessageQueue(), it reads the queue from the session and returns an array where I can find the messages and keys, if I order and replace the keys, how do I set them in the session?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to set the message queue, you need to clear it first with the initial `getMessagequeue()` call. You're not changing anything in the session. The session value for the message queue gets written into a protected variable in the global `JApplication` object. The first call to `getMessagequeue()` reads any session message queue data into the protected message queue variable, and `get` / `enqueue` operations during the request lifecycle involve this variable. It's written back to the session along with everything else at the end of the request cycle.

Comment: enqueueMessage adds a new message, I need to delete the 1st one before adding a new one. I found how to do that at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/TRFT0gtNIio/TsjzEeaHVcsJ

Comment: I think that works (using `$session->set('application.queue', data);`) because the `messageQueue` object that is used to output the message information isn't hydrated until the first call to `getMessageQueue()`, which occurs (at least) at the end of processing a request (during rendering). If there's any call to `getMessageQueue()` before you clear out the message queue in the session data, this approach won't be effective.